# Drupal mail send more than 1000 emails at once

Tags: email, drupal

I'm wondering it is possible to send a more than 1000 emails at once in Drupal 7 Drupal_mail function?

Comment: Better set the cron job and send them in smaller number per cron run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending from the PHP Server, probably your site will crash. If you are looking for a module which will allow you to do this in the background and much simpler in implementation(without adding hooks) you should give a try to module called [Simple Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_mail)